# Qual a origem da expressão “vai em cana”

Tags: significado, etimologia, português-brasileiro, origem, gíria

Ao referenciar o fim de uma ação a sua consequência ser a prisão, dizemos:

> Vai em cana

O que significa "Cana", no contexto da frase.

Comment: Seria devido a cana que os soldados romanos deram a Jesus como cetro de Rei, junto a coroa de espinhos e o manto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O dicionário Houaiss diz que a origem é obscura:

> **2 cana** *s.f. B infrm* **1** cadeia, cárcere, prisão <*se continuar a roubar vai entrar em cana*> **2** polícia <*fugiram porque a cana estava a chegar*> **3** situação difícil, dura de suportar <*o coitado enfrenta uma cana dura no trabalho*> ● *s.2g. B* **4** agente policial ou soldado ʘ ETIM origem obscura

O [Origem da Palavra](http://origemdapalavra.com.br/site/artigo/em-cana/), citado na outra resposta, diz que a origem vem de *cana* (a planta) por associação com grade, mas não apresenta qualquer fundamentação.

Entretanto há uma boa possibilidade de este sentido de *cana* vir do castelhano da América do Sul. Em vários países, incluindo a Argentina e o Uruguai, *cana* tem também os significados de ‘prisão, polícia’ e ‘agente policial’ [(dicionário da Real Academia Española 3)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=71nnvCA%7C71oseAg%7C71qELM8). Vários autores não duvidam em classificar *cana* neste sentido como um termo lunfardo—gíria de classes baixas de Buenos Aires, que depois se espalhou pela Argentina e Uruguai [(Real Academia Española)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NiZYfu8). Em abono desta tese está a quantidade de expressões lunfardas relacionadas com *cana*. Entre [este *Novísimo Diccionario Lunfardo*](https://martignoni.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/novisimo-diccionario-lunfardo/), o [artigo da Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cana_(lunfardo)#Palabras_y_expresiones_derivadas) e um [Diccionario Etimológico del Lunfardo](https://www.google.pt/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=%22cana%20alertar%22&oq=%22cana%20alertar%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.7157j0j4), encontrei as seguintes expressões:

> ***Encanar***, prender, pôr na prisão. ***Encane***, ato ou efeito de ser preso. ***Canero***, alguém que cumpre pena de prisão; relativo à prisão. ***Caer en cana***, ser preso. ***Estar en cana***, estar na prisão. ***morfarse una cana***, cumprir pena de prisão. ***Batir la cana***, advertir acerca da presença da polícia; delatar. ***Mandar en cana***, o mesmo que *batir la cana*; mandar para a prisão. ***Dar la cana***, surpreender alguém na prática de um delito. ***Arcana la cana***, grito de aviso da chegada da polícia ou pessoa indesejada.

Em castelhano, *encanar* aparece já em 1879 em *Beduinos Urbanos* de Benigno Lugones [(Wikipedia)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cana_(lunfardo)#Palabras_y_expresiones_derivadas):

> El punguista [carteirista] que es *encanado* (preso),*estrila* (rabia) en los primeros momentos, protesta que es inocente, invoca las leyes y derechos constitucionales, se muestra soberbio y hasta insolente

Em português só encontrei este sentido de *cana* a partir de 1960, embora isto não signifique muito por aí além, porque estas expressões podem existir na linguagem popular muito antes de aparecerem pela primeira vez em publicações do Google Books.

Quanto às origens do *cana* e *encanar* lunfardos, há mais teorias que expressões à volta de *cana*. Entre a [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cana_(lunfardo)#Palabras_y_expresiones_derivadas) e [*Mosaicos Porteños* de Luis Alposta](https://books.google.pt/books?id=7V9HhLpXtB8C&pg=PA139&dq=%22batir%20la%20cana%22%20encanar&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi24922wYDQAhUBlBQKHckCDwMQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22batir%20la%20cana%22%20encanar&f=false) encontrei as seguintes hipóteses:

> - do francês *canne*, cana, bastão;
> - do italiano *canna*, cana, porque a polícia de Verona era assim chamada por causa da cor dos seus uniformes;
> - do veneziano *encaenar*, prender com corrente;
> - de *lucana*, que seria como a máfia siciliana chamava à polícia.
> - do próprio castelalhano *caído en canastra*, ficar preso.
> - do castelhano *cana*, cã, cabelo branco, por os prisioneiros ganharem cabelos brancos na prisão.
> - de um tal comissário *Racana*, que prendia o pessoal por jogar futebol nas ruas.

Com isto tudo, parece-me que temos que concordar com o dicionário Houaiss, que a origem deste *cana* e *encanar* é obscura. Mas se tivesse que escolher um hipótese, iria pelo venziano *encaenar*. A Portugal, *cana* chegou apenas no sentido de prisão, nomeadamente na expressão *ir de cana* [(Priberam 7, 10 e 11)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/cana).

Answer (score 3):

Surgiu por causa da palavra **grades**("grade feita de canas entrelaçadas").O que originou a gíria “estar em cana”...

fonte: [EM CANA - ETMOLOGIA](http://origemdapalavra.com.br/site/artigo/em-cana/)